# How to disable dragging of Highcharts annotations?

Tags: highcharts

How to disable dragging of Highcharts annotations? Can't find any options for it. I tried to add `pointerEvents: none` to `chart -> annotations -> labelOptions -> style` but this did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `draggable = ""` in annotations property like that:

```
annotations: [{
    labels: [{
      point: 'max',
      text: 'Max'
    }],
    draggable: ""
}]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lqxt3y6m/

Or add this line before chart initialization:

```
Highcharts.Annotation.prototype.defaultOptions.draggable = '';
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e2zbhyot/

Comment: What should I do if I need to turn it on/off at runtime?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can achieve it by updating annotation with property `draggable = ""` to turn it off and `draggable = "xy"` to turn it on. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lqxt3y6m/1/.